# Formatting output from random module functions

Tags: python, random, format, output

I'm writing a program for myself that generates a loadout for this game I play. I'm nearly done, I switched from using random.choice to random.sample in order to avoid have repeats in the results but hate the formatting.

```
print("He has", random.choice(kills) + ',', random.choice(kills) + ',', random.choice(kills) + ', and', random.choice(kills))
```

Outputs:

> He has Two Handed Choke, Skewer, Skewer, and Pitchfork Stab

whereas:

```
print("He has", random.sample(kills, 4))
```

Outputs:

> He has ['Knee Snap', 'Jaw Rip', 'Body Slam', 'Choke']

How do I get a sample that outputs like the code for random.choice()?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
random = random.sample(kills, 4)
str_random = ", ".join(str(x) for x in random[:-1])
print("He has", str_random, "and", random[-1])
```

Comment: Ok, hang on. @ChristianDean

Comment: @ChristianDean Done.

Comment: Yup, I was just about to point that out to you @Julian. Nice job ;-) +1

Comment: You're overwriting `random` (so it can't be used again) and you're applying `str` to strings (which is rather pointless).

Comment: Thanks, using "random" for the variables caused errors, but your solution worked perfectly after I changed the variable names:                                                                                                  
  ldOut = random.sample(kills, 4)
  str_ldOut = ", ".join(str(x) for x in ldOut[:-1])
  print("With", str_ldOut, "and", ldOut[-1])

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to iterate over the object, adding it to a string. Try the following:

```
choices = random.sample(kills,4) #put choices in variable
s = "He has " #begin output String
for(c in choices):
    s = s + c + "," #add choices to output string
s = s[:-1] #remove final comma
print(s) #print string
```

Comment: What about the 'and' in the OP's output? Your going to have to end up doing something similar to what @Julian did in her answer.